# Using mmv, how to strip folder names of a "+"

Tags: linux, batch-rename

I have a bunch of folders with `+` instead of spaces.
I tried `mmv '*+*' '#1_#2'` as well as `mmv '*\+*' '#1_#2'` with the result

> *+* -> #1_#2 : no match.

and

> *+* -> #1_#2 : no match.

respectively.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do it as `mmv -r '*+*' '#1_#2'`

`man mmv` says,

```
-r :   rename source file or directory to target name. The target name must not
       include a path: the file remains in the same directory in all cases. This
       option is the only way of renaming directories under mmv.
```

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used mmv before, but for something like this I'd go into the folder that you want to rename files in, and in a bash shell do something like:

```
for f in *; do mv "$f" "${f//+/ }"; done
```

Someone else here showed me this, and I asked about it. the ${f//+/ } is called Bash Shell Expansion. `//+/` substitutes a space for a plus.

Comment: This also works but as the question was targeted at using mmv I favor a solution using it. Can't upvote with only 8 rep...